# OTRS slow performance main queue listing

Tags: mysql, performance, otrs

we have the problem of a very slow queue listing. If there are more than 15 tickets in a single queue it takes up to 4-5 seconds for creating the view.

This problems occure since we're using OTRS 3.1
We are running OTRS 3.1.4 with the KIX4OTRS extension on a virtualized Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

We tried yet:

- known performance tweaks provided in the manuals.
- creating extra database indexes
- installation on physical machines (no positive effects) with Ubuntu
  12.04 / 12.04.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Moved to serverfault.com, http://serverfault.com/questions/457381/otrs-slow-performance-main-queue-listing

Thanks mrml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a special behavior with Kix...

Try to disable some modules in  "Ticket -> Frontend::Agent::Ticket::MenuModulePre" in Sysconfig.

This should increase the performance...

Bye

Comment: Thanks a lot, we deactivated all features. We don't use this buttons anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any customer databases? The Queue View would display also data from the customer database so if you would use an external LDAP system or database, and that would be slow, this would also immediately affect OTRS performance.

BTW I think this would be more a ServerFault than StackOverflow question because it is not programming related.

Comment: Disabling LDAP has no influence to the performance, we already tried it :-/ - I thought about posting it at ServerFault, but there are more posts for otrs here, then at SF. But i will post it there and close this thread.